# Why I get [[ outputfile missing with filter module

Tags: context, python, filter

Why I get this error : [[output file missing

```tex
 \setuppapersize[A4][A4]
\usemodule[filter]
\defineexternalfilter
  [python]
  [
    filtercommand={python \externalfilterinputfile \space > \externalfilteroutputfile},
    output={\externalfilterbasefile.tex},
   cache=yes,
   readcommand=\typefile,
   spacebefore=medium,
   spaceafter=medium, 
  ]


\starttext

% From Sympy doc
\startpython
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')
a = Integral(cos(x)*exp(x), x)
Eq(a, a.doit())
\stoppython

\stoptext
```

With pythontex :

```tex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pythontex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}


pyconsole :

\begin{pyconsole}[][frame=single]
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')
a = Integral(cos(x)*exp(x), x)
Eq(a, a.doit())
\end{pyconsole}



 sympyblock

\begin{sympyblock}
from sympy import *
x= symbols('x')
f = x**3 + cos(x)**5
g = Integral(f, x)
\end{sympyblock}

\[\sympy{g}=\sympy{g.doit()}\]

\end{document}
```

Result :

[image: output]

Comment: You have to print your result to the console so that the output is passed to your temporary file

Answer (score 1):

Well, first you need to `print`. Second, what do you need to type exactly? Not an Python expert, but according to [documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html), (La)TeX printing is available. Only for expository purposes I defined two filters, so choose the one which fits your needs:

```
\usemodule[filter]
%It depends on your OS. In mine it's python3
\defineexternalfilter
    [pythontyping]
    [filtercommand={python3 \externalfilterinputfile \space > \externalfilteroutputfile},
    output={\externalfilterbasefile.tex},
    cache=yes,
    readcommand=\typefile,
    spacebefore=medium,
    spaceafter=medium]
%We copy settings to save typing
\defineexternalfilter[pythonformula][pythontyping]
%But instead of typing, we input a formula
\setupexternalfilter[pythonformula]
    [readcommand=\samplefile] %\input should also work
\startTEXpage
%This prints verbatim text
\startpythontyping
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')
a = Integral(cos(x)*exp(x), x)
print(Eq(a, a.doit()))
\stoppythontyping

%This inputs a formula
\startformula
\startpythonformula
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')
a = Integral(cos(x)*exp(x), x)
# print(Eq(a, a.doit()))
print(latex(Eq(a, a.doit())))
\stoppythonformula
\stopformula
\stopTEXpage
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My aim is to put both output and verbatim in my document like pythontex and sympytex in LaTeX ([documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pythontex)).

Comment: @Aviroum Like [this](https://pastebin.com/9Z56X3XD)?

Comment: Yes. But How to automate the incrementation of buffers.

Comment: @Aviroum Please add a concrete example in your question so that it's easier to know what to do. IMO `pythontex` doesn't provide enough examples, so you could 

Comment: I edit my question.